# Apache Wicket: File download that would not lock the page

Tags: java, wicket

I want to create a link that would initiate a file download which would be asynchronous to the page itself, i.e. I want the page not to be locked during the file download. Should I make it be initiated outside wicket? Or is there something inside wicket that would let me set up a resource stream which would bypass the page locks?

Things I tried:

- [`DownloadLink`](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/link/DownloadLink.html) - locks the page, as stated in its doc. This was my starting point.
- [`ResourceLink`](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/link/ResourceLink.html) - did not state the locking explicitly in the doc, so I tried this, but it also locked the page.
- At this point I've investigated the code of both links a bit and noticed they both schedule the download via [`ResourceStreamRequestHandler`](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/request/handler/resource/ResourceStreamRequestHandler.html). Expecting that his kind of behavior could be just handler-specific I've attempted to schedule a custom handler I've written:

  ```
  private void sendFile(final File file) throws IOException {

      IRequestHandler fileDownloadHandler = new IRequestHandler() {
          @Override
          public void respond(IRequestCycle requestCycle) {
              WebResponse response = (WebResponse) requestCycle.getResponse();

              OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
              response.setContentType("audio/x-wav");
              response.setContentLength((int)file.length());

              String fileName = "Somethingsomething.wav";

              // sets HTTP header
              response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");

              byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[1024];
              DataInputStream in = null;

              try {

                  in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

                  int length = 0;
                  // reads the file's bytes and writes them to the response stream
                  while ((in != null) && ((length = in.read(byteBuffer)) != -1))
                  {
                       outStream.write(byteBuffer,0,length);
                  }

                  in.close();
                  outStream.close();

              } catch (IOException e) {
                   throw new PortalError("IOException trying to write the response", e);
               }
          } 

          @Override
          public void detach(IRequestCycle requestCycle) {

          }
      };

      getRequestCycle().scheduleRequestHandlerAfterCurrent(fileDownloadHandler);

  }
  ```
- This did not quite work either, so I've investigated further. I've noticed that unlike I expected, the "scheduled" request handlers would not get executed on a separate request, as I expected, but on the same one. I figured that it must be that the page gets locked for the first handler and then remains locked while the second one is executing as well. So I've attempted to force the download handler into a separate request (via an ajax behaviour):

  ```
  public void startDownload(AjaxRequestTarget target) throws DownloadTargetNotFoundException{

      target.appendJavaScript("setTimeout(\"window.location.href='" + getCallbackUrl() + "'\", 100);");

  }

  @Override
  public void onRequest() {

      sendFile(getFile());
      logger.debug("Download initiated");

  }
  ```

  I've found this [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/AJAX+update+and+file+download+in+one+blow) and hoped it could potentially be what I've been looking for. However, unsurprisingly so, the page gets locked still (I would imagine because the behaviour still has to be retrieved from the page, for which the page lock has to be acquired).

I'm at a loss where I should be looking next, especially after all this time trying to get a simple download link working. I was considering creating another web filter one layer above wicket, which could be signaled from within wicket to create the download after the wicket filter is finished with its work (and hence the page lock is already released), but that seems a bit excessive for a task like this.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: That just looks over-engineered if you ask me. 1) create servlet which can dump the file to the response (google: java FileServlet). 2) create link/button to that servlet. 3) user clicks link/button, browser does the rest. Classic solution, works flawlessly.

Comment: The solution is not quite flexible enough for a couple of reasons. Firstly, I have to generate the files on button/link click (there can be far too many of them on the page to pre-generate them all), and that requires extra dependencies and processing in the new servlet. That can be dealt with, but I also don't like the idea of having any components outside of wicket, as then I would lose the benefit of using wicket (i.e. I couldn't reach other components on the page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to download from a resource, see
http://wicketinaction.com/2012/11/uploading-files-to-wicket-iresource/ and read http://wicket.apache.org/guide/guide/resources.html

Comment: This looks exactly what I've been looking for. I'll try it out and accept if I can get it working.

Comment: This required some extra work (the resources you linked skip quite a bit, and if I had not done research beforehand, I don't think I could've made sense of these), but I've got it running. I think I might amend your answer with some extra info, if I can figure out how to format it properly.